# How to Close Mat-select Panel when Mouse is out of the box?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mouseout

Requirement is straight forward but somehow I think I am missing basic concept on the usage of `mat-select` APIs, I have also followed few Answers but none seems to work.

**Requirement:** As soon as I take the mouse away from the panel I should be able to click on the Search button.

**Current Behavior:**

1. I have to make two clicks on to close the Panel
2. Another to click on Search button.

*Note:* The Search button is always Enabled.

[image]

**Code for the above Mat-select in the image:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <mat-form-field class="full-width" >
         <mat-select   placeholder="Account Status"  
                       name="statusSelect"
                       #statusSelect="ngModel"
                       [(ngModel)]="advanceSearchFormData.statusSelect" 
                       multiple>
 <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="advanceSearchFormData.statusSelect?.length > 1" >
           Multiple
 </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option  *ngFor="let status of accountStatus" 
       [value]="status.accountStatus">
                  {{ status.accountStatus }}
   </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully, MatSelect provides a reference to the panel element, so when it is open, you can grab it and just add event listener to listen `mouseleave` event:

```
this.matSelect.openedChange.subscribe(opened => {
  if (opened) {
    this.matSelect.panel.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      this.matSelect.close();
    })
  }
})
```

And don't forget to remove event listener and unsubscribe.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-nmewhw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @dev for the workaround, I was really struggling with the APIs. Also, won't ngDestroy automatically removes the event and unsubscribe ?

Comment: Ur welcome. No, it doesn't, you should do it yourself

Answer (score 3):

I found a clear solution for this case:

```
   <mat-select #matmat placeholder="observers" [formControl]="observers"
                                [(value)]="selectedViewers" multiple> 
                                <div (mouseleave)="matmat.close()">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of allUsers" [value]="user">{{user.firstName}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </div>
     </mat-select>
```